# Is there a way to hide the unused parameter warning for the main function?

Tags: c++, gcc, sdl

I'm using SDL2, which requires that the `main` function have parameters `argc` and `argv`. I don't use these at any time in the code, so I'm getting an unused parameter warning for each one when I compile with g++.

I know I could supress all unused parameter warnings, but I would like to have them enabled for other functions. Is there a way to supress them for `main` specifically?

Comment: Add `[[maybe_unused]]` or just remove their names?

Comment: There are some [attributes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) for that. If your compiler doesn't support C++17 and you can't upgrade, then the compiler-specific  variant documented in that link will work, because GCC have had a similar compiler-specific attribute for a long time. I also recommend [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for your specific version of GCC.

Comment: And by the way, what part of SDL2 requires those two arguments for the `main` function? Are you calling an SDL2 function passing those arguments? Then you *are* actually using them, and don't need any attribute. And if you don't actually use them at all, you don't need them and could just omit them.

Comment: The function signature has to be `int main(int, char**)` for SDL2 to find it. I've removed the names of the parameters, which has worked.

Comment: make the arguments unnamed. Unnamed function arguments won't generate the warning: `int main(int, char**){return 0;};`

Comment: Let me guess, you're on Windows and use the SDL2 "main"-function library to supply a `WinMain` function which calls your `main` function? Then yes you have to supply the arguments. Or since you're using GCC, create a normal console-project which doesn't need a `WinMain` function proxy, and then you can use your own normal and standard `main` function with or without arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for SDL2 requiring you define main with `argc` and `argv` if itself doesn't use them.

You should be fine with a regular `int main()`

You can use `[[maybe_unused]]` on the parameters if you really want to